# MySQL two circles intersect created from longitude and latitude points with radius

Tags: mysql

I am creating a query in which I can select matching records based on latitude, longitude and distance (KM) information. Inside each record the latitude, longitude and distance is stored. Inside my query I give a specified latitude, longitude and distance and all records which intersect with it must be selected.

Currently I have created the code below but it seems not to work correctly. I always get a 1 (TRUE) returned.

```
ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.18299 52.0238)', 4326), 10), ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',record_lng,' ',record_lat,')'), 4326), 10)) as spatially_intersects
```

Comment: Perhaps you can simply check whether the distance between the 2 points is smaller or equal to the sum of their radii - `If(ST_Distance(POINT(Long1, Lat1),POINT(Long2, Lat2))<=Radius1+Radius2, "INTERSECT","NO INTERSECTION")`

Comment: You are completely right. I was making it too difficult. Thanks.